# Why does Visual Studio treat my objects differently?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have altered a basic C++ class example to see if I really understand how OOP works. I added a `rectc(7,8)` object right after defining the class and an additional `cout` statement. However, I'm surprised that `rectc` didn't appear in the **locals** tab. `rectc` does appear under **Autos** tab, but the icon is different from the icon next to `rect` & `rectb`. What's really going on here?

```
// Rectangle Project.cpp : class constructor
//

#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class CRectangle { 
    int width, height;
    public: 
        CRectangle (int, int);
        int area() {
            return (width*height);
        }
} rectc(7,8);

CRectangle::CRectangle (int a, int b) {
    width = a;
    height = b;
} 

int main() {
    CRectangle rect(3, 4);
    CRectangle rectb(5, 6);
    cout << "rect area: " << rect.area() << endl;
    cout << "rectb area: " << rectb.area() << endl;
    cout << "rectc area: " << rectc.area() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You defined `rectc` as a global variable.

Comment: Ask youself: is `rectc` local to `main`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have VS to hand to check, but my guess is that the "Locals" tab in the debugger will only list function local variables.

Since `rect` and `rectb` were defined in the `main` function, they are "local" to that function. If you tried to access them from outside the function, the compiler wouldn't let you. More than this, the objects referred to by `rect` and `rectb` only last as long as the function does. When the function returns (that is, when `rect` and `rectb` go out of scope), they will get destructed.

`rectc`, on the other hand, was defined *outside* the `main` function. While `rect` and `rectb` have *function local scope*, `rectc` has *global scope* and can be used from within any function*. Thus `rectc` will not appear in the "locals" debugger tab.

---

*** This is not strictly true. The place referencing `rectc` will still need to be able to see its declaration. This is important when your code is split across multiple files and/or translation units. This may not mean much to you yet, but you'll get there.